# Sort large text file by length of a column

Tags: sorting, bioinformatics, large-files

I have an about 2Gb FASTA (text) file that needs to be sorted by length of its 4th column. It looks like

```
MERCURE:174:C0UT3ACXX:5:2316:18091:100842/1    +    dogpremirnas    4910    AAAAAAAAAA    DDC@BBDDDD    0    3:T>A,9:T>A
MERCURE:174:C0UT3ACXX:5:2316:18110:100902/1    +    dogpremirnas    4909    AAAAAAAAAA    DDDDDBDDBD    0    0:G>A,4:T>A
MERCURE:174:C0UT3ACXX:5:2316:18153:100840/1    -    dogpremirnas    2269    TTTTTTTTTTT    BDDB>9<@A><    0    5:C>T,9:C>T
MERCURE:174:C0UT3ACXX:5:2316:18259:100924/1    +    dogpremirnas    833    ACCGATCTCGTA    CHHFCC8ACBBB    0    6:G>C,7:C>T,8:T>C
MERCURE:174:C0UT3ACXX:5:2316:18344:100886/1    +    dogpremirnas    11734    AAAAAAAAAA    DCDCDDDDDD    0    4:C>A,9:G>A
MERCURE:174:C0UT3ACXX:5:2316:18415:100878/1    +    dogpremirnas    4909    AAAAAAAAAA    BDDCDDDDDB    0    0:G>A,4:T>A
MERCURE:174:C0UT3ACXX:5:2316:18442:100808/1    +    dogpremirnas    11734    AAAAAAAAAA    DDDDDDDDDB    0    4:C>A,9:G>A
MERCURE:174:C0UT3ACXX:5:2316:18461:100754/1    +    dogpremirnas    4914    AAAAAAAAAA    DDDDDDDBDB    0    5:T>A,6:T>A
MERCURE:174:C0UT3ACXX:5:2316:18464:100926/1    +    dogpremirnas    833    ACCGATCTCGTA    HHHFCC/=CBBB    0    6:G>C,7:C>T,8:T>C
```

and needs to be sorted by the length of the column. In the man page of the sort command it says I can specify the key, but no indication how to put in "length" into it.
I only need the lines that have over 20 symbols in the 4th column. Unfortunately, the soft that got me this result (bowtie) doesn't provide such requests either.

Any suggestions would be very welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: You can use the usual linux tools to do this, but it exceeds memory might need something else.

Comment: 1) add an extra column, containing the length of the fourth field and sort on the new field **or** 2) create your own sorting program

Answer (score 0):

I like awk for working with column data like this:

```
awk 'length($5)>20' /path/to/input > outputfile
```